# Query to create new column by analyzing data in 1st column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working in SQL Server on a project. and I have this data

### Column1

B.Ed

B.Ed

B.Ed

PTC

PTC

Now what I want with this data is that in SQL Server it should create two new columns named as B.Ed and PTC and insert "1" in fields when they occur in Column1. This is how the Output should 
[image: Output]

I have a guess that it will be done with subqueries and I tried to understand them but couldn't understand the concept. So if you can help we with SQL query that can implement what I am trying to achieve here. Sorry about formatting but I hope you all are getting my point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use case `expression` here:

```
select *, (case when ProfQual_16 = 'B.Ed' then 1 end) as BED,
          (case when ProfQual_16 = 'PTC' then 1 end) as PTC 
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update your existing table using the `case` expression

If you already have the new column in your existing table then you can directly use the update statement else you if you want you can add a new column as per your requirement.

```
ALTER TABLE EducationQualification
ADD BTech VARCHAR(127),MTech VARCHAR(127),
```

**SQL Query:**
Since I created the new column during the creation of table:

```
CREATE TABLE EducationQualification
(
Qualification VARCHAR(100),
BTech   VARCHAR(100) NULL,
MTech   VARCHAR(100) NULL
)

INSERT INTO EducationQualification
(Qualification,BTech,MTech)
VALUES
('B.Tech',NULL,NULL),('B.Tech',NULL,NULL),('B.Tech',NULL,NULL),('M.Tech',NULL,NULL)

SELECT * FROM EducationQualification
```

**Output:**

[image]

```
UPDATE EducationQualification
SET BTech = CASE
                WHEN Qualification = 'B.Tech' THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
            END,
    MTech = CASE
                WHEN Qualification = 'M.Tech' THEN 1
                ELSE NULL
            END
```

**Result After Update Query:**

[image]

Comment: thank you for your help your approach is also applicable to my problem:)